# MVC4 Ajax Form URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way to set the URL for an [asp.net-mvc-4](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-4) AJAX form? I am looking for an answer using the `Ajax.BeginForm()` syntax so that i can make use of Microsoft's model construction sorcery without needing to re-parse the url string myself.

There is a partial view that lives on `foo.com.au/getFoo` which has an ajax form in it. the ajax form will post to `Foo` controller (default), `getFoo` action.

When i am calling this from an external site (`bar.com.au`) i want it to post back to `foo.com.au/getFoo`. Instead it is posting to `bar.com.au/getFoo`. Is there some way to tell the Ajax Form to post to the full URL instead of just the relative path?

**Motive** 
For those of you who suspect hax0rz or other foul play, i have built a widget which is being integrated across multiple client sites. I am now building an authentication plugin for this widget. The widget does not redirect them to my website for authentication, therefore i want it to post back to my domain with the results of the username/password input form.

Comment: "external site" means what?

Comment: I would assume its a site which is not part of the original domain

Comment: External site means i do not have control over or knowledge of its URL, or access to its resources.

Comment: Motive added for all the internet concerned citizens

Comment: I am confused. This is my thought. I am in domainA. I want to post the form to that action method which resides in domainB and the form is in domain A. First please confirm my understanding and how can we post the form to domain B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass it in through the Ajax-options instead of supplying it in the overloaad of BeginForm:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        Url = Url.Action("getFoo", "Foo", null, Request.Url.Scheme)
    }))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This answer works perfectly.
To anyone seeking to do this, remember that you need to set the `access-control-allow-origin` header to `"*"` so that the cross domain JS will still work

Comment: @Kenneth : I am confused. This is my thought. I am in domainA. I want to post the form to that action method which resides in domainB and the form is in domain A. First please confirm my understanding and how can we post the form to domain B?

Comment: You need CORS for that, see the second comment from @DavidColwell.